# How can I detect if element is not display on screen do to scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user scrolls down on my website, I'd like to detect when the very top header is out of view.  Is this possible with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionaed by @RoryMcCrossan, you can calculate it yourself.

If you want a little more flexibillity, try this jQuery plugin:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

it'll let you query the DOM based on whether the element is within the visible viewport.

For example:

```
$("div:in-viewport")
```

will only return `div`s that are currently visible.

You can also query for elements that are not visible, based on where they are. Mainly:

```
$(":below-the-fold")
$(":above-the-top")
$(":left-of-screen")
$(":right-of-screen")
```

Check out the link above for more info, and the download.

---

If you want to use this library to query for elements not currently shown,
regardless of where they are, then use this:

```
$("div").not(":in-viewport")
```

---

So, assuming your header has an ID of `header`, you might use this:

```
var $header = $('#header');

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    var isVisible = $header.is(':in-viewport');
    // Now show, hide, or do whatever you want...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the position of the element, using `offset()` against the position of the window scroll. Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $header = $("#header");
    var headerBottomPos = $header.offset().top + $header.height();
    if (headerBottomPos < this.scrollTop()) {
        // header is not being displayed
    }
});
```